# IdentityServer login error in MVC Core: Error loading external login information

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019, identityserver4

environments: MVC Core 3.1, VS2019, IdentityServer4

I created the asp.net core web application in VS2019 with 'individual user account'. Modified it to use IdentityServer to authenticate users(We have an authentication service built with IdentityServer4). When I login by clicking "OpenIdConnect" button, I was correctly redirected to IdentityServer where I entered username and password and was successfully authenticated (I can verify that from IdentityServer's log). But when redirected back to my application, I got this error "Error loading external login information.".

[image]

IdentityServer should not be the problem, since We have other applications built with Web Forms and MVC successfully authenticate with it. But this is our first MVC Core project using IdentityServer, so I don't know if I am missing some options.

I've searched all Internet but find no solution. Please help.

My code in Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = "[my-identityserver-url]";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            options.ClientId = "[my-client-id]";
            options.ClientSecret = "[my-client-secret]";

            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            options.UsePkce = true;

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            };
        });
}
```

Settings on the IdentityServer -

Login Redirect URIs: https://localhost:44313/signin-oidc

Post Logout Redirect URIs: https://localhost:44313/

Scopes: openid, profile

Grant Types: hybrid, client_credentials

CORS Origins: https://localhost:44313/

https://localhost:44313/ is the web application's url.

Comment: In all of the MVC client IS4 implementations I have done in .Net Core, I have used the ResponseType of "Code" (and only Code).  I believe PCKE only works if the ResponseType is set to "Code".  Try changing your ResponseType.

Comment: OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken == "code id_token". When I put only "code' there, I got error: "Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client"

Comment: Your comment is a bit confusing.  The line I am suggesting should read "options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;"  Is that what you tried?

Comment: Also, what is the "AllowedGrantTypes" option for your MVC client on the IdentityServer4 side?  (in the Config.cs)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried options.ResponseType = "code" and got that error. I don't see  "AllowedGrantTypes" option on the IdentityServer4 side. I will post that code.

Comment: While the contents of the startup.cs on the IS4 side might prove useful, what I was asking about is actually in the Config.cs (usually). This will include the Apis and Clients.  Note, this file may contain secrets depending on your setup, so be sure to take those out.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean. AllowedGrantTypes are hybrid and client_credentials

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220818/discussion-between-bryan-lewis-and-martial).